# Override Java version when building a Cordova project with gradle

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

I am trying to build a Cordova project using gradle as a build tool. In the Cordova project I have my own plugin that requires Java 1.7.

In the build.gradle that comes with Cordova the java version is 1.6.
build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}
```

The build.gradle comes with a great big warning that says it is a generated file that should not be edited, the way to customize the gradle build step is - as I understand - to create a build-extras.gradle file.

I have created a build-extras.gradle file and tried the following:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to work. I still get an error when I build my project.

Error:

```
> strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
>         switch (action) {
>                 ^   (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to setup gradle to make this work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been trying to solve the same problem, and came here hoping to find an answer! Anyway, although there was no answer, your mention of `build-extras.gradle` put me on the right track, and the following now works for me...so thanks.

To begin with I thought I might as well try using the same syntax as you, so as to try to work out what was wrong. As far as I can tell it fails because the `build-extras.gradle` file is not magically merged into `build.gradle`, but is instead loaded and executed using the Gradle `apply from` approach. And since this happens before the `android` closure it is too early in the process, and those `android` values override our 'extra' values.

(I don't have time to delve more than I need to into Gradle or Groovy, so apologies if my terminology is not precise...)

However, I could get it to work if I used the `postBuildExtras()` method.

If you look at the bottom of the `build.gradle` file that is generated by Cordova you'll see that if such a method (i.e., `postBuildExtras`) exists on `ext`, then it gets called. Since this is the last thing in the configuration script then I guess the point of this method is that we can use it to override anything.

I therefore ended up with this as my `build-extras.gradle`:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
}
```

I actually had this working quite early in my investigations but kept trying other approaches since I suspect this technique will fail when we try to have multiple `build-extras.gradle` files -- which, given that we're both talking specifically about Cordova plugins, is very likely.

There is a technique that looks promising for plugins, which is to use the `<framework>` element in `plugin.xml`, but with this approach I could never get the plugin-specific module to load/import/whatever. I'll take another look at this when I get to plugin #2, but for now the technique described above gets me a big leap further on where I was this morning, so thanks again for the `build-extras.gradle` clue. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the answer of Mark, i got a solution to add the `build-extras.gradle` into the `plugin.xml` file. So it will be added automatically to the platform folder to the right place.

```
<source-file src="src/android/lib/build-extras.gradle" target-dir="src/.." />
```

Answer (score 0):

The next rows have been found and updated.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
```

to

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

The main point is changing  build.gradle file that are located in the next folder `\platforms\android\` But keep in mind there are also presented other build.gradle files with other paths.