# Cordova plugin error on build, diamond operator isnot suported in source 1.6 use source 7

Tags: java, android, cordova, intellij-idea, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app with ionic framework, and within the app I'm creating a cordova plugin for use native android java.

The problem is that when building I get an error that is relative to the cordova plugin about sources.
I have installed java 1.8 jdk and jre.

Here is the ouput of building

```
D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\guille\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
Running: D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaD:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\src\com\gldl\communications\UDPComms.java:178: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
        List<byte[]> listgen = new ArrayList<>();
                                             ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
1 error
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.314 secs

D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\guille\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest>
```

the IntelliJ IDEA is configured to use API 22 and javas 1.8

I think the problem is in the cordova plugin, maybe I have to add to the plugin.xml something similar to the android sdk API

ex:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
```

Part of the code of the cordova plugin is part of an old android studio project that work perfect and compiled without this error.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've found this: Override Java version when building a Cordova project with gradle
at: [Override Java version when building a Cordova project with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386152/override-java-version-when-building-a-cordova-project-with-gradle)

I've changed for version 1_8:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Now I have a very heavy error of too many lines to put it here, but the begining is:

```
D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\guille\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
Running: D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Androide_prj\test_comms\plugintest\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved installing java 7

cordova is not compatible with java 8

Comment: This should rather be a comment, not an answer!

Comment: why? is what one of the cordova developers told me at cordova.slack.com, that cordova is not compatible with java 1.8. I can't say anymore and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error with the diamond operator, used it like:

```
    List<byte[]> listgen = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
```

Perhaps this will work with your Cordova Plugin.