# cordova build error Exit code 1

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, ngcordova, cordova-cli, phonegap-cli

I have created referred -  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#installing-the-cordova-cli

for creating first cordova android app. I was able t create project and add android platform, but could not build cordova, following error appeared.
Following is the commands executed from command prompt

[image]

Comment: I have exact same problem. Could you solve it?

Comment: Don't use screen shots of text. Copy and paste the text directly into the question!

Answer (score 0):

It looks more of a network issue. The gradle download will fail if you are using restricted proxy network. In case of network restrictions, you can work around this issue by following the steps below:

> 1) Download the required gradle version zip file from gradle [distribution link](https://services.gradle.org/distributions) and save it in local folder.
>   2) Navigate to  PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders folder and edit GradleBuilder.js file
>   3) Change the line from `var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';` to `'var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'file:///local/path/to/folder/where/gradle/zip/is/saved/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';` and save the file
>   4 Try rebuilding android build.

You can also try the following as quick fix,

> 1) In command prompt execute the following command: 
>   `export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///local/path/to/folder/where/gradle/zip/is/saved/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`
>   2) Exeucte the following command: `cordova run android`