# Cordova build android error: Error code 1

Tags: node.js, cordova

I have been trying many online tutorials for weeks now on how to build an android app for my web app using cordova and/or phonegap CLI and/or the cloud service, but I keep getting it wrong.

I lastly tried to use the cordova CLI as follows:

- I downloaded and installed java jdk
- I downloaded the Android SDk (verified the variables JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and PATH)
- I downloaded and installed nodeJs
- Installed cordova via: npm install -g cordova (which I verified the version to be 6.2)
- I created a new folder for the cordova project and entered the folder
- I Added the android platform thus: cordova platform add android
  When I ran: cordova build android, I had an error like that [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254222/cordova-build-error-exit-code-1/38091651#38091651).

I discovered gradle was the problem and I donloaded and used it locally as @Gandhi suggested, then I had a shorter response now (the portion in red ink of the picture in the above link). I have been researching in vain and I really think I am now stuck.
I run on windows 10, an hp notebook, 64-bits, core-i3 
[cordova build android  CLI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ivzC.jpg)

Comment: After you installed the android sdk, configured ANDROID_HOME and updated the path, you have to run the androidcommand to actually download the sdk tools and android platform. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304599/error-in-building-android-app-using-apache-cordova

Comment: I just downloaded and updated all of the SDK pludins it recommended on startup, and still to no avail. I really do not understand what the message in red ink is saying. I  really think something else is the problem rather than the android sdk. I still see some _gradle_ in the message

Comment: Then your problem is in Gradle. For running Gradle, firstly add the environment variable GRADLE_HOME. This should point to the unpacked files from the Gradle website. Next add GRADLE_HOME/bin to your PATH environment variable. Usually, this is sufficient to run Gradle.

Comment: I just unpacked gradle and added my vaiable GRADLE_HOME and included the PATH (echo %GRADLE_HOME%/bin), both manually, but I still got the message in red ink. The message in red points to the files: <project path>/platforms/android/gradlew and build.gradle with some additional arguments, but I don't understand them